# How to write audiences JSON object in App Center push notification?

Tags: json, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to make a post request to send push notification to an Audience using App Center Push. But, I'm confusing about how to define/write the audience json object, how is the model of audience?

I saw this codes in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/rest-api#send-a-notification-to-an-audience)

```
{  
    "notification_content": {    
        "name": "Cyclists and Dog Lovers",    
        "title": "Crossover Event This Weekend",    
        "body": "Do your dogs like to ride bikes? Come to our crossover event this weekend.",    
        "custom_data": {
            "eventDate": "06/01/2020", 
            "eventTime": "08:00 AM"
        }  
    },  
    "notification_target": {    
        "type": "audiences_target",    
        "audiences": ["dog-lovers", "cyclists"]  
    } 
}
```

What is "dog-lovers" & "cyclists" and how can I define their json object? Where?

Answer (score 0):

`dog-lovers` and `cyclists` are the names of the audiences targeted by this notification. Those audiences must either already exist in App Center Push, or you must create them using the REST API as described in the link you provided. You can't create the audience on the fly as you send the notification.